# Error al mandar peticion ajax a php - Max input Vars excedido

Tags: php

Estoy recibiendo peticiones Ajax y me encuentro con este error, cabe aclarar que lo que mando no son más de 100 variables. Alguna idea de que puede estar ocurriendo aqui?

Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0

Intente aumentar el máximo del input vars pero al mostrar la información no se ve reflejado el cambio en php.ini

Comment: Recuerda reiniciar el servidor posterior a la modificación del archivo php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes modificar el archivo php.ini, y modificar el valor de max_input_vars, ese archivo depende de que stack estas usando (XAMP, WAMP, Apache en Linux, etc).

Si usas XAMP en windows en la parte inferior de la derecha cerca de la hora hay unos iconos, ahi esta la opcion de modificar el php.ini

abrelo con notepad y cambia el valor de esa configuracion